# Syntax Error 'SCRIPT1002' using Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, internet-explorer

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
>   index.php, line 4 character 37

I got this error in IE11 and my `.click()` handlers are not working on the page where the error occurs (only in IE11). On lines 1 to 10 I got some standart meta tags so that shouldn't be the problem (I removed them and still received the error).

Because I got a lot of code and I don't know where exactly this error occurs. What's the best way to find the responsible code for this error?

Here is the `index.php` file referenced in the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <?php
        include("database/connect.php");
        include("modul/session/session.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_appinfo`;";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        if (isset($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) {
            $appinfo = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_ind_design` WHERE tb_user_ID = $session_userid;";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        if (isset($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }
    ?>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $appinfo["description"];?>">
        <meta name="author" content="A.Person">

        <title><?php echo $appinfo["title"];?></title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <?php
            if (preg_match("/(Trident\/(\d{2,}|7|8|9)(.*)rv:(\d{2,}))|(MSIE\ (\d{2,}|8|9)(.*)Tablet\ PC)|(Trident\/(\d{2,}|7|8|9))/", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], $match) != 0) {
                echo '<link href="css/evaStyles_ie.css" rel="stylesheet">';
            } else {
                if(isset($row)){
                    echo '
                    <meta name="theme-color" content="'.$row["akzentfarbe"].'"/>
                    <style>
                        :root {
                            --hintergrund: '.$row["hintergrund"].';
                            --akzentfarbe: '.$row["akzentfarbe"].';
                            --schrift: '.$row["schrift"].';
                            --link: '.$row["link"].';
                        }
                        html {
                            --hintergrund: '.$row["hintergrund"].';
                            --akzentfarbe: '.$row["akzentfarbe"].';
                            --schrift: '.$row["schrift"].';
                            --link: '.$row["link"].';
                        }
                    </style>
                    <link href="css/evaStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    ';
                } else {
                    echo '
                    <meta name="theme-color" content="'.$appinfo["akzentfarbe"].'"/>
                    <style>
                        :root {
                            --hintergrund: '.$appinfo["hintergrund"].';
                            --akzentfarbe: '.$appinfo["akzentfarbe"].';
                            --schrift: '.$appinfo["schrift"].';
                            --link: '.$appinfo["link"].';
                        }
                        html {
                            --hintergrund: '.$appinfo["hintergrund"].';
                            --akzentfarbe: '.$appinfo["akzentfarbe"].';
                            --schrift: '.$appinfo["schrift"].';
                            --link: '.$appinfo["link"].';
                        }
                    </style>
                    <link href="css/evaStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    ';
                }
            }
        ?>

    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="loadScreen">
            <span class="helper"></span><img class="img-responsive" id="loadingImg" src="img/loading.svg"/>
        </div>

        <div id="pageContents" style="opacity: 0;">

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <div id="naviLink">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse bg-color fixed-top" id="slideMe" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="modul/dashboard/dashboard.php">
                            <img src="<?php echo $appinfo["logo_path"];?>" width="<?php echo $appinfo["logo_width"];?>" alt="Logo">
                            <span style="margin-left:20px;"><?php echo $appinfo["title"];?></span>
                        </a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                                <?php
                                    $userID = ($mysqli->query("SELECT ID FROM tb_user WHERE bKey = '$session_username'")->fetch_assoc());
                                    $sql1 = "SELECT mg.ID, mm.file_path, mm.title FROM tb_ind_nav AS mg INNER JOIN tb_modul AS mm ON mm.ID = mg.tb_modul_ID WHERE mg.tb_user_ID = " . $userID['ID'] . " ORDER BY mg.position";
                                    $result = $mysqli->query($sql1);
                                    if (isset($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
                                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            $link = '
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" navLinkId="'. $row["ID"].'" href="'. $row["file_path"].'">'. $translate[$row["title"]].'</a>
                                                </li>
                                                ';
                                                echo $link;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        $link = '
                                        <li class="nav-item" id="editNavLink">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="modul/settings/settings.php">'. $translate[15].'</a>
                                        </li>
                                        ';
                                        echo $link;
                                    }
                                ?>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 offset-md-1">
                        <div page="<?php if(isset($_SESSION["user"]["currentPath"])){ echo $_SESSION["user"]["currentPath"]; } else { echo "modul/dashboard/dashboard.php";} ?>" id="pageContent">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->

            <footer class="footer" id="slideMeFoot" style="display: none;">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="foot-link" href="modul/settings/settings.php"><?php echo $translate[16] ?></a><i class="text-muted"> | <?php echo $_SESSION["user"]['username']; ?></i><span class="text-muted">©<a href="https://your-website.ch"> HTML Link</a> | 2018 | <?php echo $appinfo["title"];?> <a href="https://github.com/link-to/repo">v.1.0</a></span>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Own JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var translate = {};
            <?php
                foreach ($translate as $key => $value) {
                    echo ("translate['".$key."'] = '".$value."';");
                };
            ?>;
        </script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly which line of code is causing the problem.

Comment: Well there's not any script on this line. Or am I searching in the wrong file?

Comment: What is on line 4 of the rendered html? (Right click > View source)

Comment: The error is shown in the browser, so it relates to the *rendered* html, not the original source.

Comment: @Turnip #This Meta-Tag: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Of course, it's IE, so don't expect it to get the line number right - check 3-4 lines either side of that as well...

Comment: The best way to find the error is to keep remove lines until it stops coming up. (or remove all the lines then add them back in... your choice).  You can do this one at a time or a few at a time - eg remove 10 it stops so add them back and remove 5 - until you narrow it down to the offending line.

Comment: @freedomn-m Just added the first lines of the rendered html (See Edit)

Comment: ^ this. I'd remove whole blocks of PHP one at a time and then individual JS files until the problem disappears. Then you know where to look.

Comment: @freedomn-m I already tried to remove all meta tags and almost everything I found in the head section. But the error still appeard

Comment: The only inline script element is the one where you fill your `translate` variable, so go check the output in that place, whether that looks correct. (Btw., heard of JSON?) If that’s not it, then the error is most likely in your `js/index.js` file.

Comment: If error still appeared after removing stuff in the head - then the error is not in the head.  Unfortunately IE isn't the best at telling you where the error actually is - do you get the same problem in Chrome?

Comment: @CBroe I removed the whole script and still got the same error. I also tried to remove every function in `js/index.js` and test it again, but every time I received the error. (Yes, heard about JSON, but excuse my laziness :-) (Work in progress))

Comment: @freedomn-m Everything is working fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably resides in your `dashboard.js` file. On [line 4](https://github.com/baloise/EVA/blob/master/modul/dashboard/dashboard.js#L4) you have a `setInterval()`:

```
var id = setInterval(frame, speed, );
```

There is either a parameter missing or you accidentally added an extra comma.

To reproduce this you can include the `dashboard.js` file on any page and the syntax error will be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using arrow syntax like value.foreach(param => {}); It can also cause this error in IE 11 since it does not understand shorthand functions. Need to change the function to be: value.foreach(function(param){});

Comment: Yes, IE11 doesn't support promises, and there's no great way around the issue.

Comment: @dilettante the way around this issue would be to use a polyfill, for example Bluebird.js